# Hyperledger fabric deployment (real network)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have created an application using "Hyperledger Composer"
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html

Its working fine on my local machine and I am able to access REST API's over local network.

I would like to setup real network. What I mean is multiple hosts and peers. I have been trying to figure out steps/guideline to setup a real fabric v1 network and deploy application on it, but haven't had any luck yet.

My Questions are

What are the steps of deploying real Fabric 1.0 network with multiple hosts, peers? 
How to deploy application in real network (once its setup)?

Appreciate any direction here.

Comment: This is not really a stack overflow question.   Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for guidance on what and how to ask.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a couple of linux VMs with ssh keys configured so you can ssh without prompting for a password you may try https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment

Comment: there is also an Ansible deployment tool being developed outside of Hyperledger by another of the developers here https://github.com/litong01/fabric-deploy