# Hyperledger-fabric setup in real systems

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have been working on hyperledger-fabric node sdk v 1.0 and successfully created prototype based on dockers . However now I wanted to implement this architecture on real systems. I haven't found any documentation which helps in setting up environment in real systems. All I found is to set up different peers and organization using dockers and then invoke transactions etc.Can we connect different computer machines using dockers and then spin up the network on all these different machine to create private blockchain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyperledger fabric deployment (real network)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378316/hyperledger-fabric-deployment-real-network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. For that, first of all you should define your network configuration. Then, you would create the artifacts that are required for the network: the keys, the channel artifact, the genesis block... You would follow the steps that are defined on the Fabric documentation to [Build your first network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html). Also, you should  share the public keys and the genesis block.

Then, in each machine you would install the docker images, like is explained in the [Fabric documentation](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html). After that, you would define the containers that you are going to set up in each machine. You do that on the docker configuration files (docker-compose.yaml, docker-base.yaml...). There, be aware of defining well the docker network configuration. You have more info about it in the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775844/error-starting-up-a-network-nodes-in-different-vm-failed-connecting-to-ordere).

At the end you would switch on each container executin the docker-compose.

I don't know if I've given you enough information. If not, ask again please.

Comment: Hey @Urko can you share your docker consfiguration files with me? I have installed docker images on both machines and channel configuration on one host .

Comment: @Urko kindly share you docker-compose.yaml, docker-base.yaml files

Answer (score 0):

Docker is good for production systems. Docker swarm can be used for connecting multiple machines.